# The link between the monotony of a function, and its limit

Tags: limits, functions, convergence-divergence

Let's assume I have a convergent function f, as x approaches to $$+\infty$$.
Is-it true to say that it exists a real x0, such that forall x>x0, f is either increasing or constant or decreasing ?
(And if it is true, how do I prove it ? By using the convergent in +infty definition ?)

Thanks.

Comment: The monotony of a function is how tedious it is.*Monotonicity* is the word you're looking for.

Comment: Oups sorry .. it's the first time I try to translate this notion in english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. For example, $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}=0$, but $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not eventually monotonic.

In general, you can think about this in terms of the [squeeze theorem/pinching theorem/two policemen theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem). If $g$ and $h$ both have the same limit, it doesn't matter how much some function $f$ wiggles around between them; as long as it stays between them, it must converge...

Comment: Oh yes you are right ..
In fact I have to prove that if $$\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \in \mathbb{R}$$ and f is periodic, then f is the constant function ..
It is obvious, but I can't figure out how to prove it foramlly

Comment: @Choups314: You should ask that as a separate question (and link back to this one to provide context).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064012/if-a-function-is-convergent-and-periodic-then-it-is-the-constant-function