# periodic functions, proof that lim x → + ∞ sin(x) does not exist

Tags: limits, analysis, functions, periodic-functions, constants

I'm trying to figure out how to proof the next thing:
Let f be a periodic function in real numbers,that is there exists T> 0 such that f (x) = f (x + T) ∀ x ∈ R. Show that if lim x → + ∞ f (x) exists, then f is a constant function. Deduce from this that lim x → + ∞ sin(x) does not exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a function is convergent and periodic, then it is the constant function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064012/if-a-function-is-convergent-and-periodic-then-it-is-the-constant-function)

Comment: I don't have the function to be convergent in my hypotheses

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.